# Is it effective to take Polearm Master and Sentinel on a Barbarian?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization

I'm building an 8th level Zealot Barbarian for an ongoing campaign and I'm thinking about taking the Polearm Master and Sentinel feats because it's a pretty nice combo to protect your party and to apply rage bonus damage.

I would take variant Human for one of the Feats but lose some ability points. With point buy array of 15,14,13,12,10,8, I would end up with Str: 16 Dex: 14 Con: 16 -> the rest don't matter. (It's my first character so if I did something wrong let me know.)

Will this build be effective in combat, or does taking both of these feats end up with a stat dump that makes the character useless?

I would go for a Goliath Zealot instead with no feats but mean stats. I don't know a lot about the party make-up, so I don't know exactly what combat roles are needed. But I like to play characters that are team players and the feats will give that to me.

Comment: Effective in what way and compared to what? What role do you want to play in combat / what are your expectations for what you want to contribute?

Comment: If you take regular human, you can end up with 16 16 16 9 9 9 and then take the feats at 4 and 8.  I am not sure I understand your Stat line.  If you take vHuman, you get the first feat at 1, the second at 4, and then you can boost a stat (Con or Dex) at 8. (16, 14, 18 for example).

Comment: If you are taking feats, and you only care about the physical stats, you can't do better than variant human. Variant human give you 2 attribute increases as well as a feat, which would cost 2 attribute increases normally, giving you 4 effective attribute increases. The only race that can match that is mountain dwarf, which doesn't give you useful even attributes until your first ASI which you spend on attributes.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: "_With point buy array of 15,14,13,12,10,8, I would end up with Str: 16 Dex: 14 Con: 16_" How? With variant human, how would those stats give you two 16s?

Comment: @NathanS: I'd suggest you avoid making minor edits to fix formatting or phrasing (that don't address the main problem with a question) as the first edit after the question is closed. [If you edit the body of a question within 5 days of closure, it will generally cause the question to appear in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/335251) - but if the edit doesn't materially address the problem causing the question to be closed, those in the queue will simply vote to leave it closed, and it won't appear in that queue again. (Just a note for the future.)

Comment: @V2Blast Ah, I didn't know I was stopping it from turning up in the queue; I'll refrain from this in the future, sorry.

Comment: @NathanS: Thanks for understanding :)

Comment: [This might help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72253/9552) to clear up the question